# jQuery - $('.myClass').detach(), then .clone(), hey where's my nested table?

Tags: jquery, html, clone

So I have this div with a table that I'm trying to re-use for multiple entries in a JSON database.

```
<div class="myButton">
                <table>
                    <tr id="currentVersion">
                        <td class="subj">Current Version</td>
                        <td class="abt"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="baseReqs">
                        <td class="subj">Basic System Requirements</td>
                        <td class="abt"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="reasonsTo">
                        <td class="subj">Reasons to Update to This Version</td>
                        <td class="abt"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="reasonsNot">
                        <td class="subj">Note the Following Before Updating</td>
                        <td class="abt"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

And the jQuery that I'm using detaches the div, then clones it for each entry in the database.

```
buttonCreator: function(data){
    var buttonElement = $('.myButton').detach();
    $.each(data, function(index, version){

                    var newButton = buttonElement.clone();
        newButton.attr("id", version.id).addClass(version.status);
        newButton.html(version.shortName);
        /*the next line fails! because the correct element does not exist, evidently*/
        $('.currentVersion .abt', newButton).html(version.currentVersion);
        /*this just prepares the div to be seen correctly, and handle events*/
        newButton.children().hide();
        newButton.click(versionilizer.handleButtonClick);
        $('#myVersionInfo').append(newButton);
        });
},
```

But I cannot get the table to be copied by .clone().  I've looked at the API and it seems to say that it should be copied the nested data and any relevant event handlers(if present), but that hasn't been my experience so far.  I tried passing (true) and (true, true) as arguments to both .clone() and .detach(), but this was not successful either.  Not certain what I need to do to copy the contents of the div.

Comment: If you detach, and then clone, you'll append the clone, and the original is never added back to the dom. do you really need to detach?

Comment: I'm detaching b/c the template for the div/table is empty of actual data, so I detach it b/c it does not need to be displayed.  Also, am I not correctly storing the reference in 'var buttonElement = $('myButton').detach()'?

Comment: You are, i just commented without actually reading the code. I corrected my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You destroyed the content of `newButton` with `newButton.html(version.shortName);` It no longer contains a table but only what was in `version.shortName`.

Comment: Oh, well that's useless isn't it! :)  Better not do that anymore.